# Sticky footer with long text

Tags: html, css

I have long text in my page. I want my footer to stick to the bottom and text should be hidden under the footer so I can scroll the text. There should be no text under the footer. How can I do that?

```css
.container {}
  footer {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
       }
```

```html
<html>
<div class="container">
  <p>Long long text</p>
  <footer>My footer</footer>
</div>

</html>
```

Comment: position: fixed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should achieve this by using `fixed` position instead of `absolute`

```css
.container {
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
  footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 0;
   text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</div>

<footer>Footer Here</footer>
```

Comment: It actually worked but some text is hidden under the footer?

Comment: that text can be displayed after scrolling

Comment: Even after scrolling

Comment: increase `padding-bottom` to `container` as per your requirement